# I can't interact with my HTML map in anything other than Chrome?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<map>` placed over an `<div>` which contains some elements that react to rolling over the `<area>` elements within it.

It looks like this in Dreamweaver's "design" interface:

[image]

My map is placed over the actual graphics using CSS like so:

```
img#dial-map
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Where this is the actual map:

```
<img src="anatomy/view/dial/dial.png" id="dial-map" usemap="dial">
<map name="dial">
    <area id="click-ansible" shape="poly" coords="412,419,376,447,313,474,248,487,247,434,327,415,374,377" href="#">
    <area id="click-cadreon" shape="poly" coords="487,245,478,313,455,366,416,417,378,380,429,299,434,246" href="#">
    <area id="click-orion" shape="poly" coords="418,73,453,117,482,191,484,242,431,244,422,180,378,111" href="#">
    <area id="click-ensemble" shape="poly" coords="247,1,311,10,368,35,415,70,378,108,312,66,244,53" href="#">
    <area id="click-reprise" shape="poly" coords="73,69,111,39,176,8,242,2,243,53,172,66,112,108" href="#">
    <area id="click-magnaglobal" shape="poly" coords="245,487,186,481,114,450,71,417,110,377,175,423,246,432" href="#">
    <area id="click-airborne" shape="poly" coords="69,414,37,373,12,316,2,244,55,244,68,322,106,375" href="#">
    <area id="click-analytics" shape="poly" coords="2,242,11,171,33,120,71,74,109,109,70,168,54,241" href="#">
    <area id="click-mb3" shape="poly" coords="257,430,178,422,120,384,82,340,140,305,163,337,206,360,262,364,317,342,348,305,404,340,384,367,324,413" href="#">
    <area id="click-um" shape="poly" coords="307,134,245,116,246,56,309,68,375,109,418,178,430,237,429,288,404,339,350,303,368,246,358,198,344,169" href="#">
    <area id="click-initiative" shape="poly" coords="80,339,63,289,58,235,72,171,109,112,176,67,243,56,242,119,192,128,152,159,126,206,122,261,137,306" href="#">
</map>
```

`dial.png` is a PNG with no content (fully transparent image).

I then use JQuery to apply the animation that I want when I roll over each `<area>`:

```
$("map area").each(function()
{
    $(this).mouseover(function()
    {
        // ...

    }).mouseout(function()
    {
        // ...

    });

});
```

---

Everything is working perfectly in Chrome, but nothing happens when I try it in Internet Exporer(8) or Firefox(7). To elaborate, nothing happening is inclusive of the below:

1. The cursor doesn't change to the pointer as it should when I roll over the areas.
2. The animations I added in my JQuery that are working in Chrome don't run.
3. Clicking the areas doesn't do anything (inclusive of adding a `#` to the URL as expected).

I have a feeling that the issue lies in the CSS and the positioning of the map ontop of my graphics. Can anyone see why this wouldn't be working as expected?

---

> Demo link:
>   https://projectavian.com/files/mb/dial.html

Comment: Try investigating at what level things are breaking down. To start, see if `alert($("map area").length)` gives the right number (11) in browsers other than Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<img ..... usemap="#dial">`

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a go when I get into the office tomorrow :)

Comment: Yeah, the surprising thing is that Chrome would play ball without the #. I got your dial working here as a local file. Nice effect. The code makes slightly more sense with `destLeft` and `destTop` calculations in the closure like `marginTop` and `marginLeft`. That way, there's less work for the processor on mouseover, but it's not a big deal. I made a couple more improvements but nothing too significant. It's quite simple to give `inner` and `outer` tabs different jog offsets but conform that 8px seems about right for both.